# Netdata in a docker swarm environment

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, netdata

I'm quite new to Netdata and also Docker Swarm. I ran Netdata for a while on single hosts but now trying to stream Netdata from workers to a manager node in a swarm environment where the manager also should act as a central Netdata instance. I'm aiming to only monitor the data from the manager.

Here's my compose file for the stack:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  netdata-client:
    image: titpetric/netdata
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    environment:
      - NETDATA_STREAM_DESTINATION=control:19999
      - NETDATA_STREAM_API_KEY=1x214ch15h3at1289y
      - PGID=999
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - netdata
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]

  netdata-central:
    image: titpetric/netdata
    hostname: control
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    environment:
      - NETDATA_API_KEY_ENABLE_1x214ch15h3at1289y=1
    ports:
      - '19999:19999'
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - netdata
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  netdata:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

Netdata on the manager works fine and the container runs on the one worker node I'm testing on. According to log output it seems to run well and gathers names from the docker containers running as it does in a local environment.

Problem is that it can't connect to the netdata-central service running on the manager.

This is the error message:

```
2019-01-04 08:35:28: netdata INFO  : STREAM_SENDER[7] : STREAM 7 [send to control:19999]: connecting...,
2019-01-04 08:35:28: netdata ERROR : STREAM_SENDER[7] : Cannot resolve host 'control', port '19999': Name or service not known,
```

not sure why it can't resolve the hostname, thought it should work that way on the overlay network. Maybe there's a better way to connect and not rely on the hostname?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: as this question might come up - the firewall (ufw) on the control host is inactive, also I think the error message clearly points to a problem with name resolution.

Comment: I tried using the service name instead of the host name which helps to solve the resolve issue but not sure if it connects to the right endpoint as it can't connect to netdata then.

Answer (score 0):

Your API-Key is in the wrong format..it has to be a GUID. You can generate one with the "uuidgen" command...

https://github.com/netdata/netdata/blob/63c96aa96f96f3aea10bdcd2ecd92c889f26b3af/conf.d/stream.conf#L7

Answer (score 0):

In the latest image the environment variables does not work.
The solution is to create a configuration file for the stream.
My working compose file is:

```
version: '3.7'

configs:
  netdata_stream_master:
    file: $PWD/stream-master.conf
  netdata_stream_client:
    file: $PWD/stream-client.conf
services:
  netdata-client:
    image: netdata/netdata:v1.21.1
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    depends_on:
      - netdata-central
    configs:
        -
          mode: 444
          source: netdata_stream_client
          target: /etc/netdata/stream.conf
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    environment:
      - PGID=999
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /etc/passwd:/host/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/host/etc/group:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    deploy:
      mode: global


  netdata-central:
    image: netdata/netdata:v1.21.1
    hostname: control
    configs:
      -
        mode: 444
        source: netdata_stream_master
        target: /etc/netdata/stream.conf
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined
    environment:
      - PGID=999
    ports:
      - '19999:19999'
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd:/host/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/host/etc/group:ro
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```